# code segmentation fault when assign value to struct variable

Tags: c

I am learning Stack in C and try to implement stack using array in C. This code I am using from https://codewithharry.com/videos/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-hindi-24

I create struct stack below.
In the main , I create a struct stack s and assign a value of 10. While executing the code, there is segmentation fault happened. I tried to lldb in VS code. it shows below error.

Please help me how to fix this code segmentation fault. What is the reason for segmentation fault?

`Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x25)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// creating stack
struct stack
{
    int size; //store the size of stack
    int top; //store index of top most element
    int *arr; //to hold the address of the array
};

// Check if stack is empty
int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == -1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct stack *s;
    s->size = 10; // This line has exception occured with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x25)
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int)); //reserve memory in heap
    
    // Check if stack is empty
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty");
    }

    // Pushing an element manually
    s->arr[0] = 7;
    s->top++;
 
    // Check if stack is empty
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        printf("The stack is not empty");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct stack *s;` is a pointer to the `struct stack`, it is not initialized, you have to allocate memory to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
struct stack *s;
s->size = 10;
```

`s` is a pointer to a stack. What stack object is it pointing at, none, hence the error. You have to create an stack and point at it, or use one directly.

```
struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
s->size = 10;
```

or

```
struct stack s;
s.size = 10;
```

The second one creates a stack object on the stack.

Comment: Thanks @pm100 this solution works. 
should I cast the return value of malloc
`struct stack *s = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`

Comment: @Jignesh23 have fun reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc